# What's the alternative to @ResponseBody if I'm not using annotations but if I'm using a multiaction controller?

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I have a multiaction controller to handle all related requests. I have created a method to handle an ajax request and the method is expected to return a string value as the response. This spring application is NOT "mvc:annotation-driven".

The controller with the method that handles the ajax call:

```
public class UserController extends MultiActionController { 

    private UserDelegate userDelegate;

    public void setUserDelegate(UserDelegate userDelegate) {
        this.userDelegate = userDelegate;
    }

    public String AjaxExample(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session) {
        String ip = request.getParameter("ip"));
        String sysName = userDelegate.getSysName(ip);
        return sysName;
    }

    //Several methods to handle other requests ...
}
```

Using jquery I'm able to successfully call the 'AjaxExample' method above. The jquery function is shown below:

```
function callAjax() {
                        var ip = $('#ip').val();
                        $.ajax(
                            {
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "AjaxExample.do",
                                data: "ip=" + ip,
                                success: function(response) {
                                    alert(response);
                                },
                                error: function(e) {
                                    alert('Error: ' + e);
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    }
```

The problem I'm facing is how do I return a String without using @ResponseBody annotation?

Am I allowed to use annotation on just this one method? 
To be honest I actually tried that by setting the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` tag in my application config file and annotating the 'AjaxExample' method with @ResponseBody. That didn't work, spring still recognized the string as an unresolved view.

I've never configured spring using annotations and my understanding on the same is limited. Did the @ResponseBody annotation not work because I didn't annotate my controller with @Controller and because I didn't annotate the method with @Request? But I do have a bean definition for them in my application config file and rest of the methods in the controller work fine.

Please bear with my ignorance and enlighten me on how to get this method to return a string to my ajax call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the return type to void then write the response directly to the `HttpServletResponse`.

```java
public void AjaxExample(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session) {
        String ip = request.getParameter("ip"));
        String sysName;
        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(out);
        try {
           out.print(sysName);
        } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

Comment: Just had to add PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(out) to the solution as the OutputStream doesn't have a print method associated with it. Thank you very much for the solution.